# Node JS cheerio does not extract attribute value

Tags: javascript, node.js

I im using this [code](https://runkit.com/embed/kw5i2hawmj69) and you can test it [here](https://npm.runkit.com/request)

I put correct path to the `data-video` attribute but I always get `undefined`. It works in Chrome but does not in Node. I don't know where i do it wrong?

```
var trailer_url = $('#title-overview-widget > div.vital > div.slate_wrapper > div.slate > a').attr('data-video');
console.log(trailer_url);
```

Comment: The delivered page definitely differs by the IP address set for `X-Forwarded-For`. Google cloud address misses `div.slate_wrapper`, but my ISP-provided IP gets it.

Comment: Yes you are right i removed headers ip and i get correct value for trailer id...but i need to set ip of usa if i want to get usa movie titles...otherwise i get movie titles that is translated from country ip...thanks it fixes my problem

Comment: Can i set fixed X-Forwared-For to return always USA? I im on idea to not include ip but force X-Forwarder-For to return always USA (eather way if client ip is from France, Canada, Mexico etc.)

Comment: does `cheerio` provide a `.data('video')` like JQuery?

Comment: it provides with attr() it works perfect..i just put another USA ip in above code and all is working perfectly